# `*id_to_cluster` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop

Tags: rust

The error occurs only if I uncomment the line of code `max_cluster.map(|i| i.size+=1);`, my intention is to change the content `max_cluster` contains, please offer me some suggestions.

```rs
fn fast_match(
    cluster_ids:Vec<u32>,
    id_to_cluster: & mut HashMap<u32, LogCluster>,
    tokens: Vec<String>,
    include_params: bool) -> bool {
    let mut max_sim:f32 = -1.0;
    let mut max_param_count:i32 = -1;
    let mut max_cluster: Option<& mut LogCluster> = None;
    let mut cluster: Option<& mut LogCluster>;
    for cluster_id in &cluster_ids {
        cluster = id_to_cluster.get_mut(cluster_id);
        let seq_1 = &cluster.as_ref().unwrap().log_template_tokens;
        let res= get_seq_distance(seq_1, &tokens, include_params);
        let cur_sim = res.0;
        let param_count = res.1;
        if cur_sim > max_sim || (cur_sim == max_sim && param_count > max_param_count){
            max_sim = cur_sim;
            max_param_count = param_count;
            max_cluster = cluster;
        }
    }
    if max_sim >= SIMILARITY_THRESHOLD{
        // max_cluster.map(|i| i.size+=1); 
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

Some other code related

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug, Default)]
pub struct LogCluster {
    size: u8,
    cluster_id: u32,
    log_template_tokens: Vec<String>
}


fn get_seq_distance(seq_1:&Vec<String>, seq_2:&Vec<String>, include_params:bool)-> (f32, i32){
    if seq_1.len() == 0{
        return (1.0, 0);
    }
    let mut sim_tokens:i32 = 0;
    let mut param_count: i32= 0;
    for item in std::iter::zip(seq_1, seq_2){
        if item.0.eq(&PARAM_STR.to_owned()){
            param_count +=1;
            continue;
        }
        if item.0.eq(item.1){
            sim_tokens +=1;
        }
    }
    if include_params{
        sim_tokens += param_count;
    }
    let ret_val: f32 = (sim_tokens as f32/ seq_1.len() as f32) as f32;
    (ret_val, param_count)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try storing the id of the max and then mutate it via index.

```rs
fn fast_match(
    cluster_ids:Vec<u32>,
    id_to_cluster: & mut HashMap<u32, LogCluster>,
    tokens: Vec<String>,
    include_params: bool) -> bool {
    let mut max_sim:f32 = -1.0;
    let mut max_param_count:i32 = -1;
    let mut max_cluster_id: u32 = 0;
    let mut cluster: Option<&LogCluster>;
    for cluster_id in &cluster_ids {
        cluster = id_to_cluster.get(cluster_id);
        let seq_1 = &cluster.as_ref().unwrap().log_template_tokens;
        let res= get_seq_distance(seq_1, &tokens, include_params);
        let cur_sim = res.0;
        let param_count = res.1;
        if cur_sim > max_sim || (cur_sim == max_sim && param_count > max_param_count){
            max_sim = cur_sim;
            max_param_count = param_count;
            max_cluster_id = *cluster_id;
        }
    }
    if max_sim >= SIMILARITY_THRESHOLD{
        id_to_cluster.get_mut(&max_cluster_id).map(|i| i.size+=1); 
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```